# Подскажите, пожалуйста, аналог словарю dic.academic

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, этимология, орфография, синтаксис

Просто при нахождении перевода он мне (и не только у меня такая ошибка, я узнала у других людей) с Нового Года выдает ошибку "ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED". Я писала в техподдержку - никто ничего не исправил. Словарь просто шикарнейший, я такого еще не встречала... Но нигде не могу найти аналогов.

Answer (score 1):

dic.academic - это не словарь, а сайт, а вот на сайте много словарей самых разных. Попробуйте войти здесь: 
https://dic.academic.ru/

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: Я образно сказала словарь

Comment: @fhijdhik,скорее всего проблема у вас. У меня например, открывается.

Comment: @Серж, у вас открывается именно перевод, после того, как ввели слово и нажали "поиск"?

Comment: @fhijdhk, именно!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно отключить прокси-сервер (расширение или программу). Может, проблема с интернет провайдером (он может блокировать доступ к сайту). Может, нужно обновить браузер.
https://remontka.pro/err_tunnel_connection_failed/